# Mismatched tag exception when parsing XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

This has become a real pain in my backside.

The URL I'm trying to parse is http://torrentz.eu/feed_verifiedP?q=ubuntu

Here's a short version of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <channel>
  <title>Torrentz - ubuntu</title>
  <link>http://torrentz.eu/verified?q=ubuntu</link>
  <description>ubuntu search</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <atom:link href="http://torrentz.eu/feed_verifiedP?q=ubuntu" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
  <item>
     <title>ubuntu 11 10 desktop i386 iso</title>
     <link>http://torrentz.eu/8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</link>
     <guid>http://torrentz.eu/8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</guid>
     <pubDate>Thu, 13 Oct 2011 15:02:06 +0000</pubDate>
     <category>apps linux applications os software</category>
     <description>Size: 695 MB Seeds: 4,613 Peers: 161 Hash: 8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</description>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

My code:

```
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    //Get Torrents
    XMLTorrentsRSSHandler torrentsHandler = new XMLTorrentsRSSHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(torrentsHandler);
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
    XMLTorrentsRSSParsedDataSet parsedTorrentsDataSet = torrentsHandler.getParsedData();
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 53: mismatched tag
```

Why the flip does it torment me like this!?

EDIT: This method was working fine until today. Perhaps the website changed but where is this flippin' mismatched tag?

Comment: You  may try DomParsing instead of sax. Check this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/489237/XML/Dom-Parser-special-character

Comment: I know you said it just started working again - but did you ever figure out what the issue was w/ this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you have Harmony on your build path?  Your code works fine with the built-in SAXParser in Oracle's JDK7u3.  If there isn't a reason to be using the harmony implementation, you should revert to the standard one.

Testcase form:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        final String document = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
                "<rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">\n" +
                " <channel>\n" +
                "  <title>Torrentz - ubuntu</title>\n" +
                "  <link>http://torrentz.eu/verified?q=ubuntu</link>\n" +
                "  <description>ubuntu search</description>\n" +
                "  <language>en-us</language>\n" +
                "  <atom:link href=\"http://torrentz.eu/feed_verifiedP?q=ubuntu\" rel=\"self\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" />\n" +
                "  <item>\n" +
                "     <title>ubuntu 11 10 desktop i386 iso</title>\n" +
                "     <link>http://torrentz.eu/8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</link>\n" +
                "     <guid>http://torrentz.eu/8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</guid>\n" +
                "     <pubDate>Thu, 13 Oct 2011 15:02:06 +0000</pubDate>\n" +
                "     <category>apps linux applications os software</category>\n" +
                "     <description>Size: 695 MB Seeds: 4,613 Peers: 161 Hash: 8ac3731ad4b039c05393b5404afa6e7397810b41</description>\n" +
                "  </item>\n" +
                " </channel>\n" +
                "</rss>\n";

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        ContentHandler torrentsHandler = new DefaultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                System.out.printf("%s / %s / %s\n", uri, localName, qName);
            }
        };
        xr.setContentHandler(torrentsHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(document)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here are my imports: 

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

I have no idea where the Harmony comes from!

Comment: Its the Harmony **implementations**, not the imports, that's the problem.  You must have them on your classpath, or you're using a strange JVM?  `java -version`, and inspect your classpath?

Comment: oh, I'm confused now lol. This is an Android app. It worked fine like this for 2 months and stopped working today. I'm sure the RSS feed was changed however I don't know what's causing the problem. Let me have a look at my classpaths

Comment: To be honest, I'm lost. Can you give me a noob proof description?

Comment: It's working fine now (without any changes). I can't see any difference in the old and new xmls. I hate these mysteries.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer if it didn't answer the question?  (I'm having the same issue and have no idea what's going on)